# How can I correct a .pgw file for a PNG image?

Tags: qgis, arcmap, gdal, georeferencing, png

I have a PNG file and I need its .pgw file to be set with NAD 83 as the projection.  I have created a .pgw file:

799
0
0
-799
-122.562
37.1946

However when I open the PNG in QGIS or ArcMap 10.2 it is not being placed in the right location.  I have looked around on how to form a .pgw file and I think I am doing it right, but something is obviously missing.  My PNG file has an associated KML which is where I got the coordinates for my .pgw file.  My PNG and.pwg files have the same file name as well.

Comment: There's obviously no coordinate system metadata so I would check that the right one is assigned or in-use when you load it. It is probably being displayed with an assumed projection that is wrong. (Best to use a spatial format like GeoTIFF that can store all this stuff but hardly anyone does unfortunately)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

gdal_translate should be a solution, particularly the **-a_ullr** and **-a_srs** options.

Example: `gdal_translate -a_ullr -122.562 37.1946 -118.1464 33.59505 -a_srs EPSG:4269 example_input.png example_output.tif`